# How to apply custom CSS to Angular Material md-contact-chips

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to apply a specific CCS to just one of my `md-contact-chips` from `Angular Material`. This is the piece of HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" style="height:20%;background:rgb(255, 255, 255);border-radius: 20px;border: 3px solid #A3AB45;margin-bottom:20px">
            <md-contact-chips id="transform-tags"
                              ng-model="contacts"
                              md-contacts="querySearch($query)"
                              md-contact-name="name"
                              md-contact-image="image"
                              md-contact-email="email"
                              md-require-match="true"
                              md-highlight-flags="i"
                              filter-selected="filterSelected"
                              placeholder="Categories">
            </md-contact-chips>
        </div>
```

And this is the `CCS` code:

```
.md-chips.md-focused {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

.md-chips {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

This works as intended but it's being applied to all `md-contact-chips`, I only want to apply it only to the one with id `transform-tags`, so I modify the `CCS` in this way:

```
#transform-tags.md-chips.md-focused {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

#transform-tags.md-chips {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

But when I do this, the `CCS` is not being applied anymore! Is there some trick I need to do to apply `CCS` to `Angular Material` elements?

Comment: are you sure that #transform-tags has one of the css classes attached? maybe it's an element beneath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#transform-tags md-chips .md-chips
{
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Hope this help.